# Why this code does not fetch query as I expect?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, sum, fetch

If I run this following `sql`

```
SELECT date, SUM(nmbr_of_guests) FROM guest_tbl WHERE date = "2015-06-30"
```

I am getting this :

[image: after running query]

This what I am trying to get NUMBER(SUM) OF TOTAL VALUE of the row `nmbr_of_guests` for a specific date.
What I have to do is now I wanna get the same results (shown in screen shot) when the date is dynamically input via a form.

After I created the form I put this as form `action`

```
if (isset($_POST['search'])){
$serch_text = $_POST["search_text"]; 
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","guest");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
      die ("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }       
    $searching_date = $serch_text;
    $searchroute = "select * from guest_tbl where date = '$searching_date'";
    $result = $con->query($searchroute);
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    if ($row == 0) { echo '<div style="color: red;">We could not find the Reference ID: <b>' . $serch_text . '</b>. Please refine your reference ID</div>' ; 
    } else {        
        echo '<h3>Total guest for the day : '. $serch_text .'</h3>';        
        $total_guests = mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT date, SUM(nmbr_of_guests) FROM guest_tbl WHERE date = "'.$serch_text.'"');               
        echo $total_guests;
        mysqli_close($con);
    }
}
```

Now if I select search for 2015-06-30 via form I am getting `Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\guest\index.php on line 26`

Line 26 is `echo $total_guests;`

If I change `echo $total_guests;`

To

```
echo $total_guests->fetch_assoc();
```

I am getting `Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\guest\index.php on line 25
Array`

Now the line 25 is `echo $total_guests->fetch_assoc();`

How can I get the total value (Sum of `nmbr_of_guests`) for a specific date?

Comment: You can't `echo` an array and the returned value of `total_guests->fetch_assoc()` is an array. Use `print_r(...);` to see the structure of the array and `echo` the specific key you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error says, `fetch_assoc` returns an array, so do `print_r($total_quests->getch_assoc())` and see the structure of the array. You propably will have to pick up the first one result, but I suggest you to do it using `foreach` loop.